# Sonar : Possible null pointer dereference due to return value of called method

Tags: java, sonarqube

```
if (response != null && response.getBody() != null && response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
        return new BigDecimal(response.getBody());
}
```

I am getting possible null pointer dereference due to return value of called method on above code.

Can someone please let me know the exact issue and why it's an issue?

```
response.getBody() // returns a string value
```

Thanks in advance! Please let me know if any other details are needed.

Comment: Were you able to find a fix for this issue? As the answer suggested, tried to assign getBody to a local variable but its still complaining the local variable might throw an error.

Answer (score 4):

Sonar does not know that the two consecutive calls to `getBody()` will return the same value.

So, it is really possible, from the point of view of a static analyzer, that the second call returns `null`.

I'd recommend assigning the body to a local variable, and calling the getter only once. [Here](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarqube-null-pointer-dereference-issue/235/2) is a reference from Sonar community, where someone reported this behavior as bug and received a similar response.

A static analyzer actually *cannot* prove that the two calls will return the same value, unless `response` is of a final and immutable type. And no static analyzer I've tried yet goes to the length of trying to prove that.